# unable to get the Templaet refernce values using angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I am trying to send data via template reference variable on button click, but I'm getting error **`Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`**.

PFB my code:

**.ts code**

```
sample = "Angular";

data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mr. Nice" },
  { id: 2, name: "Narco" },
  { id: 3, name: "Bombasto" },
  { id: 4, name: "Celeritas" },
  { id: 5, name: "Magneta" },
  { id: 6, name: "RubberMan" },
  { id: 7, name: "Dynama" },
  { id: 8, name: "Dr IQ" },
  { id: 9, name: "Magma" },
  { id: 10, name: "Tornado" }
];

check(ds) {
  console.log(ds.value);
}
```

**.html code**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
   <input type="text" id={{x.id}} name={{x.name}} [(ngModel)]="sample" #ds="ngModel">
</div>

<button type="button" (click)="check(ds)">Check</button>
```

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT here i am not displaying the data and by using the template variable i am trying to get the data from the input

Comment: Try using formArray, Reactive Forms, if it's large form.

Comment: the code has already been developed with out using that

Comment: Okay, try using trackBy as discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423#issuecomment-237123496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below, but this is more complex

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
    <input type="text" id={{x.id}} name={{x.name}} [ngModel]="sample" #ds>
</div>

<button type="button" (click)="check()">Check</button>
```

**TS File**

```
@ViewChildren('ds') inps: QueryList<ElementRef>;

check() {
    console.log(this.inps);
    for (var x in this.inps) {
      if (x == "_results") {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.inps[x].length; i++) {
          console.log(this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.value)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

With some lines of code, you can achieve what you want

```
if (!this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.value) {
  this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

Updated the stackblitz also, please check

**Updated code**

```
check() {
  let checkids = [2, 3, 6];
  for (var x in this.inps) {
    if (x == "_results") {
      let id;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.inps[x].length; i++) {
        id = this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.getAttribute('id');
        if ((checkids.indexOf(+id) != -1) && !this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.value) {
          this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.style.borderColor = "red";
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pw7bnb)

Comment: a small change can u just show how can i change if id =2,3  are empty then i need to change the border color of that particular input id with 2 & 3 and disable button

Comment: what u did is correct but  ur checking empty fields only . here  we have id=2,3,6 assume then while clicking on check button is should check whether these id contained input fields are empty or not entire fields required validation  only  given  id has to check

Comment: here i can apply array also right in the OR condition  if ((id == 2 || id == 3 || id == 6)  here as i have id =[2,3,5,8,9,10,55,66]

Comment: Yeah you can, that's what I am updating my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180509/discussion-between-madpop-and-javascript-lover-skt).

Comment: Ok this is my last request could plz update it array

Comment: Yeah doing ;-) please give me 10 mins

Comment: @Madpop updated the answer and stackblitz also. Please check now

Comment: if it is string also it works right  (checkids.indexOf(+id) ?

Comment: @Madpop yeah it will work, that's why it is `+id` instead of `id`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using the template variable inside of an `ngFor` loop.
This produces something like:

```
<div>
 <input #ds>
 <input #ds>
 <input #ds>
 ...
</div>
```

Hence, the reference of `#ds` is not distinct outside of your `ngFor` loop. If you place the button within the div (so that you have a button for each row) it will work.

Comment: ok but i cant use in the div as there are other forms also depended on it and i can use ng model also as ngmodel is used my other variable so my only chance is getting the template reference only

Comment: But what do you expect the value of `#ds` to be if you place it outside of your loop? I don't understand your requirement, yet. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: my requirement is i want to validate the certain input i mean if want to check id=3 & 5 fields are empty or not if empty i have display border line

Comment: then use CSS classes with the `.ng-invalid.ng-touched` classes .. ?

Comment: @Madpop why don't you try using rectiveforms ?

Comment: I agree with @CruelEngine. For dynamic forms you have to use the `ReactiveFormsModule` and then build your form in your class (the typescript code) instead of your html template. I think it won't work with the normal `FormsModule`.

Comment: @CruelEngine as this has alerady been  developed with out using reactive or template forms so thats why more trouble

Comment: Alternatively, if your data (form) always has the same elements, you can use explicit `input` elements for each instead of using the `ngFor`. With explicit `input`s you can have distinct references and access their values separately.

Comment: adding to what @KimKern said , with the help of ``ReactiveFormsModule`` , you get better with validations as well .

Answer (score 1):

Using @Javascript Lover-SKT's answer as reference , and your problem will be solved using the below solution :

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data; let i = index;">
    <input type="text" id={{x.id}} name={{x.name}} [ngModel]="sample" (ngModelChange)='test($event,i)' #ds>
</div>
```

in your ts :

```
test(event , index){
 console.log(index + "-" + event) ; 
//here you'll get both the value and the index of data that is changed .
}
```

hope this simplifies your solution